# Order a query using a class method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a query ordering method within a class I made work.

I wrote the following, hoping that whenever I would pass a query as parameter, it would order it for me:

```
public static void Ordenar<T>(IEnumerable<T> query, string columna, string orden)
    {
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(orden) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna)))
        {
            if (orden == "ASC") query.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetField(columna).GetValue(query));
            if (orden == "DESC") query.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetField(columna).GetValue(query));
        }
    }
```

to no avail. I cannot manage to make it work like this:

```
db.Thingys.OrderBy(x=> x.Name);
```

How can I "select" this field I want to order the query by generically?
Please help. D: I'm using ASP.NET MVC3

Comment: Sorry for being slow here, but what's wrong with the LINQ `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` methods? Why do you need a custom version?

Comment: When you say it cannot work, do you mean using the exact code above? Your method does not return the sequence 'query'. Did you expect it to be ordered as if 'by reference'? That won't happen with IEnumerable.

Comment: I'm trying to order the query by the pattern I pass by parameter.
I didn't know it wasn't possible to order it "by reference". Anyway, the method doesn't work: the query doesn't get ordered, even before the method ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the merits of whether this *should* be done, here are some things that were wrong with your code.

First, you need to *return* the result of the LINQ query. LINQ operators do not alter the source sequence itself.

Second, the `columna` parameter presumably corresponds to the name of a field of the *elements* in your sequence, not of the sequence itself. Thus, you need to call `GetField` on the generic type `T`, and `GetValue` on each element (as assigned to the `x` parameter).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Ordenar<T>(IEnumerable<T> query, 
    string columna, string orden)
{
    if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(orden) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(columna)))
    {
        FieldInfo orderField = typeof(T).GetField(columna);

        if (orden == "ASC")
            return query.OrderBy(x => orderField.GetValue(x));

        if (orden == "DESC")
            return query.OrderByDescending(x => orderField.GetValue(x));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx for Dynamic Linq which will allow you to specify sorting and/or filtering based on strings (eg. for user inputs)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is interesting.